# Cannot create document from template in document library

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, document-template, 2019

I have a fresh install of SP 2019 on premise. It will not let me create a Word document in a document library from a document template in the Modern experience.

1. Create a new document library
2. Click the "+ New" button. It only offers to create a new Folder or Link

I check the Advanced settings of the doc lib. It says:
Allow management of content types: No
Template URL: Blabla/Forms/template.dotx

I try the Classic experience. Ah! This will let me create a document from a the library template. New document opens up in Word, but when I want to save it, Word asks me whereto? Of course I want to save it to the doclib, but Word has no idea about it.

3. OK. Advanced settings again, I set
   Allow management of content types: Yes

The template is shaded because now templates are set on content types. In settings I can list and add content types. The Document content type is already there and in its advanced settings I see that its template is set to /Bla/Forms/template.dotx

4. Back to doclib to "+ New", but no this template is not in there, still only Folder and Link.
5. Back to settings to Add new content type. I pick "Empty Word (dotx)". It is by default set to use template "/Templates/template.dotx?csf=1&e=xGu815"
6. Back to list and "+ New". Aha, NOW I suddenly see BOTH the default template, and the new one I created.
7. I select to create a doc from the default "Document" content type. Then it does not open a new document in Word but adds a new Document to the document library. OK so I click it in the library to open, but then it downloads Document to my hard drive.
8. OK so I try to create a doc from my "Empty Word (dotx)" template, but then it just downloads template.dotx to my hard drive.

Am I missing something very basic here? Seems like document libraries should just work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

It’s default behavior that there are only Folder and Link in the New drop down menu in SharePoint Online modern experience.

We need to configure Office Online Server in this SharePoint farm.

You can check the post: [New Document option missing in Modern Document Library](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a9eaaa2c-0882-4ecc-9bcc-34a76db14efd/new-document-option-missing-in-modern-document-library?forum=SP2019)

Comment: After changing the link of the template to /Templates/template.dotx as per Mr. Bears suggestion the template appears as a Word icon under the +NEW button as it should. This makes me think I already have OOS installed since I can see the templates in the list under the +NEW button.How can I see if I have OOS installed? Previously it was just a white "document" icon. I have also tested a template based on Excel and it has the same problem. The last response in your link suggested a known error with Word files only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the link `/Templates/template.dotx` in step 5, instead of `/Templates/template.dotx?csf=1&e=xGu815`.